# C++ where I'll need local extension or foreign method?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, refactoring

I'm not familiar with C++ enough to know where those 2 very similar refactorings (introduce local extension and introduce foreign method) will be needed. I know cases that forces to use those, but I can't figure sample classes that will need this "trick". I'm making C++ refactoring tutorial, to help new developers, but it looks like I need yours help too :)

If you used it, please tell me in where and why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the terminology ("local extension", "foreign method"), but why do you believe that this would be unique to C++?

Comment: @Oli I need to know if there are some pupular classes, that misses some important or commonly used feature, that needs to be added this way, so it makes those refactorings often used with THAT class(es).

Comment: what? Maybe it's just me, but you're making *zero* sense. What are these refactorings, and if *you* don't know of situations where they are needed, then why do you think they have a place in a tutorial? (And why do you assume that your tutorial would help new programmers? A tutorial in *forcing* a certain refactoring onto C++, despite the author being unable to see where it would *make sense* doesn't sound like a tutorial that would make the reader a better programmer.)

Comment: @jalf I want to make tutorial about every refactoring mentioned by **Martin Fowler in his book**, with C++ code examples. I have problem with only those two. Problem with providing real-life sample, that C++ developers may someday face during their work.

Comment: @dantuch: could you describe the refactorings then, since neither me nor @Oli are familiar with them under those names? (And I'd still argue that a tutorial written based on hearsay rather than personal experience is only going to detract from the reader's IQ, despite your intentions)

Comment: @jalf, sure, (thanks for your time btw.) following links are ~copy/ paste from Fowler's (and my desprition of those refactorings are made in my native language - polish, so I'll use those links) - http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-foreign-method http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-local-extension . I don't want to just translate them from Java to C++, but I'm willing to find better and "more real" examples :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Foreign" methods are methods that operate on, but aren't members of a class. In Java, that just means (static) methods of other classes that take the first class as an argument. In C++, you'll need to be aware of *free* functions. Unlike Java , in C++ methods can exist outside classes. `int main()` is the most famous one. The STL is also packed with free functions. Just have a peek in  alone.

For Java, the site you linked advises that ["foreign methods are a work-around"](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-foreign-method)  and suggest "Introduce Local Extension" as a alternative refactoring. In C++, free functions are not a work-around. That means there's much less pressure to introduce local extensions.

Furthermore, in C++ functions are not virtual by default, and objects are often passed by value. This means that the "introduce local extensions" technique often fails.

I hope this goes to show the fundamental problem with your approach: you're taking refactoring techniques for Java, which address specific Java weaknesses, and try to convert them into C++ which has a rather different set of weaknesses. Even where it works, it's often unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, but I need ask something. So if a method is outside class (in C++) I don't have to mention where "it should belong"?. Add something that will tell "this should be encapsulated with that class, but somewhat it isn't, so this method is just HERE,  and not THERE (where it should be). How do you in C++ handle situations, when in Java that work-around was necessary? **How it should be done, to get clear code?**

Comment: @dantuch: You're continuing to use Java assumptions. In C++, you have free functions, outside classes. That not only means that code _can_ be outside classes, but often it _should_ be. This is especially the case when you are writing code that's not fundamental to the class, such as these extension methods. And then there's no point documenting that the method is HERE, where it should be.

Comment: So those 2 refactoring techniques should be marked with "dont read that!" for C++ developers?

Comment: After reading this http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184401197 - *How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation*, and some more things, I'm sure that you were right. Thanks.